# Accuracy of GPU for scientific computing

Tags: gpu

An electrical engineer recently cautioned me against using GPUs for scientific computing (e.g. where accuracy really matters) on the basis that there are no hardware safeguards like there are in a CPU.  Is this true, and if so how common/substantial is the problem in typical hardware?

Comment: yes... that's right... all those massive compute clusters built with GPUs are totally useless and essentially just random number generators. All hardware is subject to random errors - a single high energy photon emmitted by a radioactive decay event in a ceramic package can flip bits somewhere inside the cpu and totally kill the system... or it might not.

Comment: @MarcB I'm not a conspiracy theorist!  See the links in my answer below for an illustration of past problems.  I basically want to know if these have been adequately fixed in more recent hardware.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, modern GPUs fit extremely well for scientific computing and many HPC applications are being at least partially ported to run on GPUs, for the sake of performance and energy efficiency.
Unlike older GPUs, the modern ones (take NVIDIA's Fermi or Kepler architectures, for example) provide fully standardized IEEE-754 formats, for both single and double precision, so you should be able to use these just like you do on a modern CPU.

Answer (score 4):

I found a few (older) papers on this, but it does seem the problem has been fixed in cards with compute capabilitity >= 2.0.

- [Fay, Sazegari, Connors. A Detailed Study of the Numerical Accuracy of GPU-Implemented Math Functions.](http://www.gpgpu.org/static/sc2006/workshop/Apple_GPUintrinsics.pdf)

> Current GPUs do not support double-precision computation and their
>   single-precision support glosses over important aspects of the
>   IEEE-754 floating-point standard[1], such as correctly rounded results
>   and proper closure of the number system.
>   ...
>   Our results show that there are serious errors with the GPUs' results
>   at certain edge cases, in addition to the incorrect handling of
>   denormalized numbers.

- Karl E. Hillesland and Anselmo Lastra, "GPU Floating-Point Paranoia." In Proc. GP2, August 2004.
- [GPUBench Test: Precision.](http://graphics.stanford.edu/projects/gpubench/test_precision.html)
- Guillaume Da Graca and David Defour, "Implementation of float-float operators on graphics
  hardware." In Proc. 7th conference on Real Numbers and Computers, July 2006.
- [Wikipedia's CUDA limitations section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compute_Unified_Device_Architecture#Limitations)

> Double precision (CUDA compute capability 1.3 and above)[14] deviate
>   from the IEEE 754 standard: round-to-nearest-even is the only
>   supported rounding mode for reciprocal, division, and square root. In
>   single precision, denormals and signalling NaNs are not supported;
>   only two IEEE rounding modes are supported (chop and round-to-nearest
>   even), and those are specified on a per-instruction basis rather than
>   in a control word; and the precision of division/square root is
>   slightly lower than single precision.

Answer (score 2):

NVIDIA has published a whitepaper that covers the details of working with floating point in general and on GPUs in particular:

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/NVIDIA-CUDA-Floating-Point.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Actually most scientific calculation generally don't need to be that accurate, because measurement errors and such largely overwhelms the errors introduced by the floating point rounding (except, perhaps in degenerate cases, like summing an array of floats in order vs in reverse order, but you'll get that kind of issues even in the CPU and nothing will warn you as well since it's working just as designed). In scientific computing, it's generally sufficient to show the result within a certain margin of errors, and to show that the margin won't cause practical issues.

Floating point are designed to be fast, not necessarily accurate digit-wise, even in a CPU, that's why we're taught always to compare floating point with an epsilon.

OTOH, calculations that actually need precise rounding rules to the last digits, like accounting or number theories, should consider using fixed point arithmetic (e.g. decimal module) which lets you specify exactly the rounding rules.