# GPU use in unix

Tags: r, gpu

I was wondering if there can be any graphic card in a unix server (basically cluster). I am interested in using GPU power for quick statistical computation using R. I tried to intall "rpud", it said "cannot find nvcc, check CUDA install"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia's CUDA article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) has some good general information and sample code in C and Python.

You need a compatible GPU and you need to install the tools from NVIDIA.

These tools are called CUDA Development tools.  nvcc is a C compiler for the GPU.

So, it can not find your CUDA Toolkit, perhaps because you did not yet install it or there are some file path settings that are incorrect.

[NVIDIA CUDA Getting Started For Linux](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html)

[NVIDIA CUDA Getting Started for Windows](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, It may sound stupid question. I was little confused as the unix doesnt have any graphical interface, would it have graphic card at all? I understand the linux and windows cna have it,,but I am not sure about the unix,, which is a cluster with 16 nodes

Comment: You can use a GPU for computation without using it for graphics. There are some specialty configurations that combine multiple GPUs for high performance; I haven't had a chance to play with one, though.

Comment: I am not even sure if the server has any graphic card. Tried to use  "lspci" but command not found and dont have root access to use it. IS there any other way to first find out if there is any grpahic card installed?

Comment: Try `grep -i chipset /var/log/Xorg.0.log` I get ATI Radeon HD 5700... and no I don't have CUDA on this Linux box.  Note that this won't work if X is not used at all.

Comment: These also work for me (giving me Radeon 5700 series again), though gives warnings for not being root:  `lspci -nn | egrep "VGA|Display"`  or `lshw -C video | grep product: `   Credit: http://askubuntu.com/questions/72766/how-do-i-find-out-the-model-of-my-graphics-card

Answer (score 1):

There are server-grade GPU cards.

Help picking a card:

[What are the differences between CUDA compute capabilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961476/what-are-the-differences-between-cuda-compute-capabilities)

Exercise caution when using older cards due to accuracy issues:

[Accuracy of GPU for scientific computing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111352/accuracy-of-gpu-for-scientific-computing)

There are R packages for this.  Notably, `gpu-tools`.